# Number of vowels in a word

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I am asked to write a program to print the number of vowels in word, but when I do that, it won't print the number of vowels, but it just kind of lists the numbers but not the sum. Can anyone help me to see what's wrong or how can I fix it? Thanks very much!

```
package vowel2;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Vowel2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
    String word = in.next();
    int v = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<word.length();i++)
    {
      char ch = word.charAt(i);
      if(ch=='a'||ch=='e'||ch=='i'||ch=='o'||ch=='u')
      {
          v++;
      }
      System.out.println(v);
    }

}
}
```

---

Running the program:

```
Enter a word: happy
0
1
1
1
1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

I want the output to be 1...

Comment: Move the print statement to outside the loop, and you'll get the result printed only once, after summing the vowels up.

Answer (score 2):

Shift the print statement, `System.out.println(v);` out of the for loop, and after it.

This will prevent the value of 'v' from being printed for every iteration of the for loop, and only the final value of 'v' will be printed once the scope of the for loop is exited .

Answer (score 2):

You put `System.out.println` inside the loop, so it will print value of variable `v` for each iteration. The solution is to put `System.out.println` outside the loop, so it will only print the total value after loop ends.

```
for(int i = 0;i<word.length();i++)
{
    char ch = word.charAt(i);
    if(ch=='a'||ch=='e'||ch=='i'||ch=='o'||ch=='u')
    {
        v++;
    }          
}
System.out.println(v);
```

Comment: Adding an explanation would be very helpful for OP.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the print statement outside the for loop so that the final statement gets printed

```
  for(int i = 0;i<word.length();i++)
    {
      char ch = word.charAt(i);
      if(ch=='a'||ch=='e'||ch=='i'||ch=='o'||ch=='u')
      {
          v++;
      }

    }
  System.out.println(v);
}
```